# How to validate a large response body contains expected values in Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, json, cypress, httpresponse

My Cypress test receives a response body that is a massive string.

In the below screenshot, you can see the response body:

[image]

As you can see, the response body contains comma-separated values.

At a later stage, this response body will be converted to a CSV file. So this string contains what will be column header values *(Case ID, SessionId)* & data for several rows.

I am able to validate that the response body contains certain values:
`expect(response.body.toString().includes("SessionId")).to.be.true`

This assertion validates that one of the column headers appears in the string.

It's possible to copy & paste this assertion for each column header I'm expecting, but I'm just wondering is there a more efficient or better way to do this? I.e. converting to something else other than a String?

Answer (score 1):

If you added your column headers as an array, [you could easily iterate over them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
let columns = ["Case ID/Risk ID", "SessionId", "Timestamp"];

columns.forEach(column => {
  expect(response.body.toString().includes(column)).to.be.true
})
```

Additionally, you could abstract the response body string as a separate variable for readability.

```
let columns = ["Case ID/Risk ID", "SessionId", "Timestamp"];
let responseString = response.body.toString();

columns.forEach(column => {
  expect(responseString.includes(column)).to.be.true;
})
```